# MS Word VBA to select any word file to open from folder path for copy/paste

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy-paste

I created 2 macros in MS Word VBA, the 1st one to select any docx file from a specified folder below as follows:

```
Macro 1
Sub test()
Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
'if the user selects a file
If intChoice <> 0 Then
'get the path selected
strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
'opens the document
objWord.Documents.Open (strPath)
End If

End Sub
```

Then the 2nd word VBA macro that I'm working on is where I want to open the master document which is document A and then call the above macro to open document b that I selected from a directory path so that I can copy contents from document B into document a which is at the end of this post.

However, the code is not working and been stuck on this for the past 8 hours and no luck finding the right combination anywhere online. The 1st macro works fine as i'm able to select any docx file and it opens successfully.
The second macro which is supposed to open the document a and then run the 1st macro which is call test and that works. but where the code is not working is after I run the call test macro, there is no copying & pasting happening such as I was under the impression that selection.whole & selection.copy would work once I run the call test macro that opens up the document b file.

so in the end, I want to open up document b from call test macro, select the data from document b to copy onto document a that's open as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciate it and not that familiar with word vba and 1st time ever doing it. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub test6()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFile As String

strFile = "C:\Users\test\Desktop\tar sheet test\documenta.docx"
If Dir(strFile) <> "" Then
Documents.Open strFile
End If

Call test
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Copy
Documents("documenta.docx").Activate '
Selection.EndKey wdStory '
Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault



End Sub
```

Comment: *...the code is not working...* - How is is not working? Wha is it doing/not doing? Please edit your question to provide some more description to what your actual issue is. Also, what debugging steps have you tried so far (have you stepped through the code line by line etc.?) and do you know if both documents are opening in the same instance of MS Word?

Comment: Hi @SamuelEverson thanks for the tips and added more clarity above. Its been 8 years since I did anything VBA and 1st time ever for MS word VBA, thanks & appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working within Word, you do not need to create a new `Word.Application` as you can use the existing instance.

I suggest you convert sub `test` to a function so that you can return the `Document` object that you opened in `test` back to your calling sub.

I also recommend to work with the `Range` object rather than relying on `Selection` as it is unnecessary most of the time.

Please try the code below:

```
Sub test6()
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = "C:\Users\test\Desktop\tar sheet test\documenta.docx"    
    
    Dim destDocument As Document
    If Dir(strFile) <> "" Then
        Set destDocument = Application.Documents.Open(strFile)
    
        Dim srcDocument As Document
        Set srcDocument = test
            
        If Not srcDocument Is Nothing Then
            srcDocument.Content.Copy
            destDocument.Range(destDocument.Range.End - 1).PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function test() As Document
    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
    
    'if the user selects a file
    If intChoice <> 0 Then
        'get the path selected
        strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
        msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
        'opens the document
        Set test = Application.Documents.Open(strPath)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Raymond, thanks so much for teachable moment and duly noted on the range part. The function code works, but got a run time error 91 of Object Variable or With Block variable not set on the sub test6 procedure for the destDocument.Range(destDocument.Range.End - 1).PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault line. Thanks again for your willingness to help as you have helped me to get closer to solving this problem. Last question, which do I run 1st, the sub procedure or function?

Comment: Can you test if `destDocument Is Nothing` is true? Is `documenta.docx` opened? @daustin5

Comment: @daustin5 I have updated my answer, the previous code will still look for `srcDocument` even if the path of `destDocument` is invalid and thus can cause error 91.

Comment: Yes, it returned Nothing according to watch window when I stepped through the destDocument. and documenta.docx is opened when I run the code up until the error.

Comment: @daustin5 What if you close `documenta.docx` and let the code opens it, is `destDocument` still Nothing?

Comment: Hey Raymond, nothing happens with the updated code you provided and documenta.docx does even open nor do I get a prompt to open the file and destdocument is still nothing

Comment: @daustin5 `C:\Users\test\Desktop\tar sheet test\documenta.docx` Is this path valid? What does `Dir("C:\Users\test\Desktop\tar sheet test\documenta.docx")` returns? It should return `documenta.docx` if the path is correct.

Comment: it does prompt me to select documenta.docx and it opened but it showed a value of '''' and got the same error message again on  run time error 91 of Object Variable or With Block variable not set on the sub test6 procedure for the destDocument.Range(destDocument.Range.End - 1).PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault

Comment: @daustin5 You shouldn't need to select `documenta.docx` as it should automatically open that file if the path is valid. What you need to select from the prompt is the document that you are copying from. Are you using the code exactly as I posted?

Comment: Now it's working as I had to get the entire path.

Comment: @daustin5 You can't run function by itself so you can only run `test6`

Comment: so just run test6 and and that's it right? Thanks so much for your time & expertise, really appreciate your support Raymond!

Comment: @daustin5 I assume that means you did not assign `strFile` the entire path.. Please accept the answer since it resolves your issue, thank you.